# OpenJPA: how to make entity use dynamic update, mutable, optimistick lock, etc

Tags: hibernate, openjpa

I'm migrating from Hibernate to OpenJPA. And there are many entities with annotations like this:
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(mutable = true, dynamicUpdate = true, optimisticLock = OptimisticLockType.VERSION).
Is there any way to use these properties in OpenJPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to claim to be a Hibernate expert, but I don't think you need to use any OpenJPA specific annotations. I'd stick to `@javax.persistence.Entity` and `@javax.persistence.Version` (on your version field).

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found the resolve either. It works without them, but it can make a big difference in productivity. But if no one know how to tune it, I think I should close this topic.

Comment: I think those properties are defaults for OpenJPA with the javax.persistence annotations so you should be all set.